# Views or Routing do not work in Angular tutorial

Tags: angularjs

I found angular tutorial, super simple, but it does not work. nothing happens when it should change the views. Here is the code:

This is the main index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html  data-ng-app="demoApp">
<head>
<title></title>

<script src="Scripts2/angular.min.js"></script>


</head>
<body >

<div >
    <div data-ng-view=""></div>
</div>

<script>

    var demoApp = angular.module('demoApp', []);

    demoApp.config(['$routeProvider', function ($routeProvider){
        $routeProvider
            .when('/view1',
                {
                    controller: 'SimpleController',
                    templateUrl: 'Partials/View1.html'
                })
            .when('/view2',
                {
                    controller: 'SimpleController',
                    templateUrl: 'Partials/View2.html'
                })
            .otherwise({ redirectTo: '/view1' });    
    }]);




    var controllers = {};
    controllers.SimpleController = function($scope){
        $scope.customers =[
            {name:'John', city:'Phoenix'},
            {name:'Jane', city:'Frisco'},
            {name:'Susan', city:'New York'}
        ];    

        $scope.addCustomer = function(){
            $scope.customers.push({ name: $scope.newCustomer.name, city:     $scope.newCustomer.city});
        }
    };
    demoApp.controller(controllers);



</script>
```

And these are 2 views:

view1.html:

```
<div class="container" >    
    <h1>View1</h1><br/>

    Name: <input type="text" data-ng-model="filter.name" /> 
    <br/>

    <ul>
        <li data-ng-repeat="cust in customers | filter: filter.name | orderBy: 'city'"> {{cust.name | uppercase}} - {{cust.city | lowercase}} </li>
    </ul>

    <br/>
    Customer Name </br>
    <input type="text" data-ng-model="newCustomer.name"/>

    <br/>
    Customer City </br>
    <input type="text" data-ng-model="newCustomer.city"/>

    <br/>
    <button data-ng-click="addCustomer()" value="Create" />


    <br/>
    <a href="#/view2" >Go to View2</a>

</div>
```

and view2.html

```
<div class="container" >    
    <h1>View2</h1><br/>

    City: <input type="text" data-ng-model="city" /> 
    <br/>

    <ul>
        <li data-ng-repeat="cust in customers | filter: city | orderBy: 'city'"> {{cust.name | uppercase}} - {{cust.city | lowercase}} </li>
    </ul>

</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems you've found a tutorial based on a older version of Angular. ngRoute has been seperated into it's own module in the later versions.

You therefore need to specify a dependency in your app:

```
var demoApp = angular.module('demoApp', ['ngRoute']);
```

And you need to [download](https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.16/angular-route.min.js) and load the script after your angular-library:

```
<script src="Scripts2/angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="Scripts2/angular-route.min.js"></script>
```

I think this should do the trick.

Update: And make sure you run your code via a webserver, and not just statically from a folder on your machine, or else you will get a "Cross origin requests are only supported for HTTP" error. http://plnkr.co/edit/ is good for testing stuff. Just choose new -> AngularJS

**Update 2**: Link to plunker testing this: http://plnkr.co/edit/IxbB1zbo7fg9He7mJ97k?p=preview

Comment: I tried to do the way you suggested: var demoApp = angular.module('demoApp', ['ngRoute']); and used 2 js links but no result

Comment: This is a small update:
I was able partially fix the problem:
So I changed the router and instead of "/view1" I just put "/"
And if I do it this way then it works. When I'm trying to redirect to view2 it also works.\
BUT(!) if I change the routing and put "/view1" then it does not work at all...

I don't get it..

Comment: What version are you using? Sounds strange. I made a plunker for myself to test, and I can't find any problems... I updated my answer with a link to the plunker.

Comment: I'm using the latest version of Angular. And the demo is taken from this tutorial http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=i9MHigUZKEM created by Dan Wahlin

Comment: Kjell, I had same problem as Jack mentioned in 1.3.10. I tried your Plunker and made a new one which works exactly as expected. However, it still doesn't work in my localhost. I am using Prepros 4.2 which provide live preview (using livereload.js maybe?). Prepros might be the problem. They say prepros is windows' version of codekit...  Here's link. http://plnkr.co/edit/DozSTscCMlA02nttaJIo?p=preview